# trim empty space on metafile side

Tags: c#, trim, metafile

I am creating in-memory metafile programmatically - for example line charts. I use Graphics.SetClip(..) and Graphics.ResetClip(..) to set max/min of X/Y axis = limit the scope of drawn datapoints.

The result is fine, except of one thing: The resulting image contains empty space on side(s). This empty space belongs to entities trimmed (hidden) by ClippingRegion.

In other words: ClippingRegion hides entities outside the region, but do NOT affect the SIZE of resulting Metafile. Metafile.GetBounds() returns the same result regardless I set ClippingRegion or not.

I need to export resulting metafile to the MS Word, to the disc, to another SW. But it is useless with these empty spaces on sides... :-(

How can this be solved? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in method

Graphics.DrawImage(Image, SourceRectangle, DestRectangle, GraphicsUnit)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx